# pyserial reading serial port and show on web page in flask

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error, pyserial

I want to read and write data from serial port with `pyserial` in `Flask`. I want to do this through a web page. The codes look like the one below. I am writing data on the web page without any problems, but I can not read data, I get a runtime error during reading. How can I implement a solution?

I'm actually trying all the ways to read data from the serial port. But I do not know which is the best way for me. What is the best way for me to display the data from the serial port to the user connected to the web page?

**I received the error:**

```
   0
def serial runtime error
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "__init__.py", line 46, in serialRead
    return jsonify(result='serial runtime error')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 251, in jsonify
    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 51, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve
this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

**python code:**

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = "asds"

    @app.route('/run_write', methods=["GET","POST"])
def serialWrite():

            print "click"
            message="selam zafer"
            if request.method == "POST":
                attempted_writeData = request.form['writeData']
                message=attempted_writeData
            try:
                if seri.isOpen():
                    print "Serial is open!"
                    seri.write(message)
                    session['serial_write'] = True
                    flash(message+" mesajiniz gonderildi..",'write')
                    return redirect(url_for("usart"))
            except Exception as e:
                    session['serial_write'] = False
                    flash(message+" mesajiniz gonderilemedi...",'write')
                    return redirect(url_for("usart"))

def serialRead():
        data =""
#        seri = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600) seri.close() seri.open()
        while 1:
                if seri.isOpen():
                 try:
#                       seri.write("hello")
                        data=seri.read()
                        print data
            if data:
                #flash(data,'read')
                return jsonify(result=data)
                 except RuntimeError:
                        print 'def serial runtime error'
                        return jsonify(result='serial runtime error')
                        seri.close()
                 except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        print 'def serial klavye hatasi'
                        seri.close()


@app.route('/background_process')
def background_process():
    try:
                print 'background '
        threadSerial = Thread(target=serialRead)
#       threadSerial.daemon = True
        threadSerial.start()
        return jsonify(result='serial runtime error')
    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)



@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    try:
        return render_template("pages/Beagle.html")
    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)

@app.route('/usart/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def usart():
    #return ("hi")
    if not seri.isOpen():
        flash("Seri baglanti kurulamadi",'connect')
        session['serial_con'] = False
    else:
        flash("Seri baglati basarili",'connect')
        session['serial_con'] = True

    return render_template("pages/usart.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    UART.setup("UART1")
    seri = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)
        seri.close()
        seri.open()

    try:

        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082)
    except SerialException as e:
        pass
```

**And Web Page code**

```
   {% extends "pages/Beagle.html" %}

{% block body %}

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
              $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/background_process', function(data) {
                  $("#result").text(data.result);
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
        </script>

</head>

<body class="body">

  <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">BeagleBone Communation</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             Usart Data
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                 <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                    Read Data BeagleBone
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <label>Send Data Input</label>
                                            <form class="form-signin" action="/run_write" method="post" role="form">
                                            <input name="writeData" class="form-control">
                                            <p class="help-block">Writing Data via USART on BeagleBone.</p>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send Button</button>
                                            {% with messages= get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["write"]) %}
                                            {% if messages %}
                                            {% for message in messages %}
                                              {% if session.serial_write %}
                                                 <div  class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible pull-right" role="alert" style="position: relative;"> 
                                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                 {% else %}
                                                  <div  class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible pull-right" role="alert" style="position: relative;"> 
                                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                 {% endif %}
                                                 {{message}}
                                                 </div>
                                             {%endfor%}
                                             {% endif %}
                                             {% endwith %}
                                            </form>
                                        </div>  

                                        <!-- <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                            Read Data BeagleBone
                            </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <!-- <h2>heading 2 -->
                                <!-- <small>sub-heading</small> -->
                            <!-- </h2> -->
                            <h3>Value read:
                                <form>
                                <small id= result  name=proglang></small>
                                <a href='#' id=process_input> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Start Read </button></a>

                                </form>
                            </h3> 

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Uou have two routes with 'run_write'. Should one be run_read. Please detail your run time execption in your question.

Comment: I am sorryy. Its wrong. Now fix it.

Comment: I'm actually trying all the ways to read data from the serial port. But I do not know which is the best way for me. What is the best way for me to display the data from the serial port to the user connected to the web page?

Comment: I think you might be best separating this app into 2 applications. 1. Is just a pyserial driver that know how to send and receive data. 2. Is the flask app that polls app 1 for changes. So you won't need any threading! App 1 will be suited for using the aysnc IO especially if you are using python 3.6 with the async / await key word.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am trying to write a Flask app which lets users write serial commands in their browser.